# How to send password in command using ssh command

Tags: java, git, ssh, jsch

I am using Jsch library to connect with my server. After connecting i am passing command which require password to proceed further hence i am passing my password in command only but nothing happens.

Code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
            jsch.removeAllIdentity();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            session.setPassword(password);
            .setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig("PubkeyAuthentication", "no");
            System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
            session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications",
                    "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connection established.");
        System.out.println("Crating SFTP Channel.");`    
        Channel shellChannel = session.openChannel("shell");
        shellChannel.connect();
        ((ChannelShell) shellChannel).setPty(true);
        shellChannel.setInputStream(System.in);
        shellChannel.setOutputStream(System.out);
        PrintStream shellStream = new PrintStream(
                shellChannel.getOutputStream());

        shellChannel.connect();
        shellStream
                .println("cd /usr/local/apache2/; ls; cd ../www; ls; git fetch origin; <mypasssword>");
        shellStream.flush();
        System.out.println("SFTP Channel created.");`
```

When i run this code git ask password to proceed further.
Note: i cannot disable password for git fetch origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code to access my linux box - it does log in successfully, but then fails to send any commands. I'm not sure if that's the problem you are having - but I will add my solution here, just in case.

Moved the `shellStream.println();` command to its own function:

```
public static void sendCommand(String c) {
    shellStream.print(c + "\n");
    shellStream.flush();
}
```

Had to make `shellChannel` and `shellStream` global variables in the process.

Changed `shellStream.println();` to `shellStream.print("\n");`, as the aforementioned refused to work.

After this line of your code:

```
shellStream = new PrintStream(shellChannel.getOutputStream());
```

Added my command sequence:

```
Thread.sleep(1000); // wait for it to connect    
sendCommand("sudo su"); // the command I tried
Thread.sleep(1000); // not sure how long you need to wait
sendCommand("mypassword");
Thread.sleep(1000);
// etc.
```

By the way, you are calling `shellChannel.connect();` twice in your code - I removed the last one.

Here's the final working version of your code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelShell;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class MyShell {

    static String user = "daniel";
    static String host = "localhost";
    static int port = 22;
    static String password = "mypass";
    static Session session;
    static Channel shellChannel;
    static PrintStream shellStream;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException, IOException,
            InterruptedException {

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        jsch.removeAllIdentity();
        session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig("PubkeyAuthentication", "no");
        System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications",
                "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connection established.");
        System.out.println("Crating SFTP Channel.");

        shellChannel = session.openChannel("shell");
        shellChannel.connect();
        ((ChannelShell) shellChannel).setPty(true);
        shellChannel.setInputStream(System.in);
        shellChannel.setOutputStream(System.out);
        shellStream = new PrintStream(shellChannel.getOutputStream());

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        sendCommand("sudo su");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        sendCommand("mypass");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        sendCommand("ls");

    }

    public static void sendCommand(String c) {
        shellStream.print(c + "\n");
        shellStream.flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
```

`Keyboard-interactive` here mean the password must be tipped with a keyboard. SSH is quite peaky about that, even if there's ways to pass a password through the command line.

The best way would be to use a pubkey auth, but if that's not a option, try to login using only `password`

```
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
```

---

Also you may just send the password using

```
session.setPassword("password");
```

Comment: I used session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "password"); but it is still asking for password in my console. my console out put : [mPassword for 'gitlab.xxx.xxx':

Comment: session.setPassword("password"); this one is also not working. It is still asking for the password. Even i tried echo 'password' and again it failed.